# How to identify the device interval ID of my XBOX / KINECT

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Actually I'm enjoying myself by playing with WSL. I would like to use my XBOX / KINECT inside the WSL. To do that,I need to enable the USB ports inside it,because as u probably know,they are disabled. I think that this project :

https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win

can help me. To make it works I need to identify what's the device ID of my XBOX,because the usbip tool does not recognize it,as it seems :

> usbip.exe list -l - busid 1-129 (05e3:0608)   Genesys Logic, Inc. :
>   Hub (05e3:0608)
>
> - busid 1-167 (05e3:0608)   Genesys Logic, Inc. : Hub (05e3:0608)
>
>   - busid 1-149 (0480:a007)   Toshiba America Inc : External Disk USB 3.0 (0480:a007)
>   - busid 1-175 (2109:0813)   VIA Labs, Inc. : unknown product (2109:0813)
>   - busid 1-89 (2109:2813)   VIA Labs, Inc. : unknown product (2109:2813)
>   - busid 1-220 (25a7:fa23)   unknown vendor : unknown product (25a7:fa23)
>   - busid 1-177 (048d:8297)   Integrated Technology Express, Inc. : unknown product (048d:8297)
>   - busid 1-122 (1058:0704)   Western Digital Technologies, Inc. : My Passport Essential (WDME) (1058:0704)
>   - busid 1-43 (2109:0813)   VIA Labs, Inc. : unknown product (2109:0813)
>   - busid 1-144 (05ac:0250)   Apple, Inc. : Aluminium Keyboard (ISO) (05ac:0250)
>   - busid 1-184 (1058:25a3)   Western Digital Technologies, Inc. : unknown product (1058:25a3)
>   - busid 1-218 (2109:2813)   VIA Labs, Inc. : unknown product (2109:2813)
>   - busid 1-209 (045e:02c4)   Microsoft Corp. : unknown product (045e:02c4)
>   - busid 1-181 (0480:a207)   Toshiba America Inc : unknown product (0480:a207)
>   - busid 1-29 (093a:2510)   Pixart Imaging, Inc. : Optical Mouse (093a:2510)
>   - busid 1-134 (0bc2:61b5)   Seagate RSS LLC : unknown product (0bc2:61b5)
>   - busid 1-158 (05ac:1006)   Apple, Inc. : Hub in Aluminum Keyboard (05ac:1006)

I'm not able to understand to which kind of interval it belongs. I went on a real linux installation and this is what I saw :

> [    2.392735] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using
>   xhci_hcd
>
> [    2.413596] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=045e,
>   idProduct=02c4, bcdDevice= 1.00
>
> [    2.413596] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,
>   SerialNumber=4
>
> [    2.413597] usb 2-8: Product: Xbox NUI Sensor
>
> [    2.413597] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: Microsoft

This is the example explained in the tutorial :

> usbip.exe list -l
>
> - busid 1-59 (045e:00cb)    Microsoft Corp. : Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 (045e:00cb)
> - busid 1-30 (80ee:0021)    VirtualBox : USB Tablet (80ee:0021)

As u can see,the memory interval where is the Optical mouse 2.0 starts with "045e" and also my xbox NUI sensor starts with "045e",so the right interval could be 1-59 ? I did :

> λ usbip.exe bind -b 1-59
>
> but this error came out :
>
> usbip: error: bind_device: error binding device on busid 1-59: err: 0

instead this command worked :

> λ usbipd.exe -d -4
>
> usbipd: info: starting usbipd (usbip 1.0.0)
>
> usbip: debug:
>   C:\work\usbip-win\userspace\src\usbipd\usbipd_sock.c:38:[build_sockfd]
>   opening 0.0.0.0:3240
>
> usbip: info: listening on 0.0.0.0:3240

The true is that I don't know what I'm doing :P Can someone help me ? 10x

Answer (score 0):

None of those numbers are intervals nor memory addresses. The "X-Y"  are dash-separated controller# and device#, while the "xxxx:yyyy" are the manufacturer ID and product ID.

In your case, the Linux system reports that 045e is the USB manufacturer ID for Microsoft, and 02c4 is Microsoft's product ID for the Kinect.

Your main device list has this entry with the same IDs:

> busid 1-209 (045e:02c4) Microsoft Corp. : unknown product (045e:02c4)

So the device ID wanted by usbipd is 1-209, that is, device #209 on controller #1.

Comment: [usbip_net_recv_op_common] version mismatch: 262 273